# Is it possible to predict the digit sum of two factors by the product's digit sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's say we have a number that is the product of exactly two prime numbers, for example:

143 = 11*13

The digit sum of the product correlates with the digit sum of the factors:

> Digit sums: DS(143) = 8 = DS(11)*DS(13)

But sometimes for this to work you have to reduce the DS to a single-DS, like for this example:

221= 13*17

> Digit sums: DS(221) =/= DS(13)*DS(17) (Product of DS(13)*DS(17) = 32)

But for single-DS this is always true: Single-DS(221) = 5 = Single-DS(32).

So, is there an easier way / algorithm to determine the digit sum of the factors of a number? Unfortunately this would be literally useless if it only works for single-DS, because then every two numbers could be the factors.

Comment: The iterated digit sum (that is, the single digit sum) is just the remainder on division by $9$. (well, instead of $0$ you get $9$.)

Comment: How big numbers are you interested in? 3-digit numbers is enough?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You should have read [MathJax help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on the page where you entered your question, and have used that to format your question. It would look much better.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I came upon this while reading about RSA-Cryptography, which uses factors that are at least 200-digits long, but it would also be interesting to maybe find a "rule" for all n < 1000 :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that for every number we have that the number and it's digit sum are congruent modulo $9$. So therefore when you calculate the digit sums of the LHS and the RHS they will eventually be same after reducing them to single digit. This is true as the number from $1$ to $9$ are exactly the residue system modulo $9$. (In fact it's from $0$ to $8$, but no numbers can have digits sum of $0$). So as the residue modulo $9$ is an invariant the equlity modulo $9$ is still valid.